# TortoiseGit, Git SVN Rebase and FETCH_HEAD slowness

Tags: git, git-svn, tortoisegit

When I do a Git SVN Rebase and the dialog window pops up to Pick, Squash, etc., the UpStream dropdown box always defaults to FETCH_HEAD now. Ideally I'd like it to point to remotes/git-svn instead. In addition, it takes almost a minute for the dialog box to stop updating (I'm assuming it's because FETCH_HEAD has a lot of things to parse).

Is there a way to either get FETCH_HEAD to stop showing, make remotes/git-svn the default or get rid of FETCH_HEAD?